# How to convert html correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, parsing, underscore.string.js

I need to convert snippets of text that contain  html tags into plain text using Javascript / Node.Js.

I currently use String.Js library for that, but the problem is that when it removes the tags (using strip_tags() functions), it also removes the new line.

E.g.

```
   <div>Some text</div><div>another text</div>
```

becomes

```
   Some textanother text
```

Do you know how I could get rid of this problem? Maybe another library?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use the DOM?

Comment: @elclanrs could you please elaborate? thanks!

Comment: If you can use the DOM, you can use `element.innerHTML` to access its guts.

Comment: Have you tried using [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2947592)?

Comment: @popovitsj - Using regex is inherently a bad idea.

Comment: @Compass the thing is that i'm dealing with content inside node.js, so how would i do that?

Comment: @deemeetree I am not familiar with node.js natively. You'll probably have to post some example code of what you're currently doing and I'll be able to see the syntax.

Comment: @EdHeal if you follow the link you'll see I was joking

Comment: How would you determine that there is supposed to be a newline between the two `div`s? There could be CSS rules that modify the default layout (e.g. making both `div`s display as inline instead of block) and those kinds of changes are not evident from parsing the HTML itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio). It will expose a jQuery like interface for you on the server side. Then it's just:

```
var html = $(htmlstring).html();
```

Then just traverse the DOM for whatever elements you want and call `$(element).text();`

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is very simple solution of your problem because I'm using reg exp and you can do what you want.

In this case we remove all tags except br tags.If you want you can remove br tag and add another tag maybe \n \t or what you want.

I hope this can help you.

Chears!!!

```
var html = "<div>Some text</div><div>another text</div><br />test<div>10</div>";
var removeHtmlTags = html.replace(/(<([^>!br]+)>)/ig,"");
console.log(removeHtmlTags);
```

Comment: Look at the OP's specific HTML.  It's not even about `<br>` tags.  This is far, far too simplistic a solution to do what the OP wants and doesn't even work on the sample HTML the OP provides.